# Software Center will not open -libcrystalhd3 needs to be reinstalled?-vlc related?-

Tags: 14.04, software-center

Recently installed `Ubuntu 14.04`. Remember having a prob installing `vlc` player through the `software center` right off the bat before any updates to to the OS. Now the `software center` will not open and every update Ubuntu has asked me to install has failed. I am not to familiar with how Ubuntu works so i might of messed up something even more through running commands on the terminal trying to figure out how to get my android phone to work through `usb` which led me to the `libcrystalhd3` needs to be reinstalled error in the terminal.

Sorry for the huge run on sentence.

I ran `software-center`

and i get this error

```
 2015-09-28 18:47:06,099 - softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.app - INFO - setting up proxy 'None'
2015-09-28 18:47:06,810 - softwarecenter.backend.reviews - WARNING - Could not get usefulness from server, no username in config file
2015-09-28 18:47:06,813 - softwarecenter.plugin - INFO - activating plugin <module 'webapps_activation' from '/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/plugins/webapps_activation.pyc'>
2015-09-28 18:47:06,909 - softwarecenter.db.pkginfo_impl.aptcache - INFO - aptcache.open()
2015-09-28 18:47:07,630 - softwarecenter.backend.reviews - WARNING - error creating bsddb: '(22, 'Invalid argument -- BDB0054 illegal flag combination specified to DB_ENV->open')' (corrupted?)
2015-09-28 18:47:07,630 - softwarecenter.backend.reviews - ERROR - trying to repair DB failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/backend/reviews/__init__.py", line 358, in _save_review_stats_cache_blocking
    self._dump_bsddbm_for_unity(outfile, outdir)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/backend/reviews/__init__.py", line 377, in _dump_bsddbm_for_unity
    0600)
DBInvalidArgError: (22, 'Invalid argument -- BDB0054 illegal flag combination specified to DB_ENV->open')
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/overrides/GLib.py:535: Warning: Source ID 68 was not found when attempting to remove it
  return super(MainContext, self).iteration(may_block)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/pkginfo_impl/aptcache.py", line 261, in open
    self._cache = apt.Cache(progress)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apt/cache.py", line 107, in __init__
    self.open(progress)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apt/cache.py", line 152, in open
    self._depcache = apt_pkg.DepCache(self._cache)
SystemError: E:The package libcrystalhd3 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
2015-09-28 18:47:08,349 - softwarecenter.db.enquire - ERROR - _get_estimate_nr_apps_and_nr_pkgs failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/enquire.py", line 115, in _get_estimate_nr_apps_and_nr_pkgs
    tmp_matches = enquire.get_mset(0, len(self.db), None, xfilter)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/appfilter.py", line 89, in __call__
    if (not pkgname in self.cache and
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/pkginfo_impl/aptcache.py", line 281, in __contains__
    return self._cache.__contains__(k)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__contains__'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/software-center", line 183, in <module>
    app.run(args)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/app.py", line 1378, in run
    self.show_available_packages(args)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/app.py", line 1316, in show_available_packages
    self.view_manager.set_active_view(ViewPages.AVAILABLE)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/session/viewmanager.py", line 150, in set_active_view
    view_widget.init_view()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/panes/availablepane.py", line 227, in init_view
    self.cache, self.db, self.icons, self.apps_filter)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/views/lobbyview.py", line 80, in __init__
    self.build()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/views/lobbyview.py", line 326, in build
    self._build_homepage_view()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/views/lobbyview.py", line 121, in _build_homepage_view
    self._append_whats_new()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/views/lobbyview.py", line 255, in _append_whats_new
    whats_new_cat = self._update_whats_new_content()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/views/lobbyview.py", line 240, in _update_whats_new_content
    docs = whats_new_cat.get_documents(self.db)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/categories.py", line 131, in get_documents
    nonblocking_load=False)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/enquire.py", line 330, in set_query
    self._blocking_perform_search()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/enquire.py", line 225, in _blocking_perform_search
    matches = enquire.get_mset(0, self.limit, None, xfilter)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/appfilter.py", line 89, in __call__
    if (not pkgname in self.cache and
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/pkginfo_impl/aptcache.py", line 281, in __contains__
    return self._cache.__contains__(k)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__contains__'
```

`

### Any ideas on what to do? Thank You.

Ok I don't remember exactly what I did but I somehow got libcrystalhd3 to install. Downloading the deb somewhere and doing something along the lines of what Zzzach posted is what did the trick I think. Anyway software center is opening now and I'm sure the autoupdates will work now too. Thanks for the tip on parsing. Now to figure out how to write files to my android phone.

Comment: Can you "parse" your error message? Don't use the `\``, use the format option of the editor.

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy libcrystalhd3`

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo apt-get install --reinstall libcrystalhd3`